# sql how to query fast a big self join table

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization, self-join

MYSQL 5.1.52-community
i have a big table with 2.5 millions rows:

i wrote this query to parse data :

[Explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBaYG.png)

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT a.id_dem FROM planning_demandes a 
        INNER JOIN planning_demandes b ON a.id_dem = b.id_dem 
        AND b.idrh IS NOT NULL 
        AND b.idrh <> 'férié' 
        AND b.idrh <> 'Pferié' 
        INNER JOIN planning_demandes c ON a.id_dem = c.id_dem 
        AND c.idrh IS NULL
```

it takes more than 100 seconds to execute .

How can i rewrite this request to be fast ? (with agregates ? should i create temporary table)

thx

Comment: Can you try moving few join conditions to where clause like... where b.idrh IS NOT NULL AND b.idrh <> 'férié' AND b.idrh <> 'Pferié' and c.idrh IS NULL

Comment: What id id_dem? What should the output look like? What indexes do you have on the table, and what does EXPLAIN show?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HBaYG.png

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.

Comment: Yes explain is here http://i.stack.imgur.com/HBaYG.png

Comment: Please try moving few join conditions to where clause like... where b.idrh IS NOT NULL AND b.idrh <> 'férié' AND b.idrh <> 'Pferié' and c.idrh IS NULL

Comment: i tried, it didnt change anything

Comment: Please try adding a dummy "id_dem" filter in where clause, assuming id_dem is a number field, try following .... where (a.id_dem > 0)  and (b.id_dem > 0 and b.idrh is not null and b.idrh <> 'férié' and b.idrh <> 'Pferié') and (c.id_dem > 0 and c.idrh is null)

Answer (score 0):

Drop one join, it is redundant.
The query is using these two join conditions: **a.id_dem = b.id_dem** and **a.id_dem = c.id_dem**,
so this also must be true: **b.id_dem = c.id_dem**

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.id_dem 
FROM planning_demandes b 
JOIN planning_demandes c ON B.id_dem = c.id_dem 
WHERE
        b.idrh IS NOT NULL 
        AND b.idrh <> 'férié' 
        AND b.idrh <> 'Pferié' 
        AND c.idrh IS NULL
```